# Dynamically Created Text Box Number Increases On Each Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've a table in the front-end where multiple text boxes are appended to the table on button click. Here's the event that I am using:

```
//Add row to the table
$('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
     var $clone = $('#tblQuesAns tbody tr:last').clone();
     $clone.find('input').val('')
     $('#tblQuesAns tbody').append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="txtQuestionName form-control" placeholder="Input Name" /> &nbsp;</td> <td><input type="text" class="txtOptions form-control" placeholder="Input Value" /><span class="addOptions">(+)</span></td> <td><input type="text" class="txtAnswers form-control" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Value" /> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger remCF">Remove</a></td> &nbsp;</tr>');  
});
```

The above works perfect, so it appends new row each time when 'Add' button clicked. There are two more buttons in the **Options** and **Answers** text box. So clicking on them, additional text boxes are created in the same column. So to take control of dynamic control, following is used where an event is bound:

```
//Add more rows for option
$('body').on('click', '.addOptions', function () {
    $(this).parent().append('<div id="txtOptions"><input class="txtOptions form-control" name="" type="text" /></div><br />');
});

//Add more rows for answer
$('body').on('click', '.addAnswers', function () {
    $(this).parent().append('<div id="txtAnswers"><input class="txtAnswers form-control" type="text" /></div><br />');
});
```

For now, the above also works. The problem is, say I navigate to another link and come back to **Question Bank** partial view, clicking on the plus sign **(+)** creates evenly text boxes each time that means double controls (Where it should create one text box for **Options** section on one click). Attached a screenshot below:

[image: Question Bank]

I tried to remove or clear the controls on page load but failed with the below:

```
$("#txtOptions").empty();
$("#txtAnswers").empty();
```

Any way I can overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this code runs in `$(document).ready()` so when you come back, it's binding new handlers for click event. You end up with more than one click handler and each one would add one row. Try removing existing click handlers if any by calling `off()` method.

```js
//Add more rows for option
$('body').off('.addOptions').on('click', '.addOptions', function () {
    $(this).parent().append('<div id="txtOptions"><input class="txtOptions form-control" name="" type="text" /></div><br />');
});

//Add more rows for answer
$('body').off('.addAnswers').on('click', '.addAnswers', function () {
    $(this).parent().append('<div id="txtAnswers"><input class="txtAnswers form-control" type="text" /></div><br />');
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly @Daniel Manta. Just slightly changed yours one to this, specifically in the off method - `off('click', '.addOptions')`.